# Can you use a JHipster reactive gateway with Okta behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, okta, spring-cloud-gateway

We have a gateway generated through jhipster that we cannot get working on production (rancher or aws). Our company has a server proxy that we need to get through to connect to Okta. It does not appear that webflux will allow us to supply our server proxy, so we get "connection refused" errors.

Has anyone run into this? Is there a workaround?

Edit:
Working fine on local.

Comment: Spring's proxy server documentation might help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server

Comment: Hi Matt, that didn't work for our case. I saw here https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot#proxy that WebFlux does not support proxy configuration. We're not behind a reverse proxy, but a regular proxy. I was hoping there was some sort of workaround, since jhipster gateway is webflux by default.

Comment: Here's a couple of resources my colleagues mentioned might help. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8882 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640554

Comment: We investigated those options and whatever they're doing does not seem to work. It's a Spring issue. It initiates a new resttemplate, so any overrides we attempt are erased. I appreciate your efforts to help. At this point, we'll just have to downgrade the app.